# Пакеты установленные не из репозиториев и их обновление в линуксе

Tags: linux, qt

На примере последних версий Qt - в репах Убунту пока 5.0 - но хотелось бы пощупать 5.2 - сорцы которого есть на офф. сайте.Если есть на борту более старая версия (4.8. *или 5.0.*) которая тоже была установленна из исходников - то сначала её придется снести, так? Как это делается?

Поделитесь вашим опытом в таких вот ситуациях.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну я тебя понял. Я вот так делаю, на примере томкат.

```
ls /opt/apache-tomcat-6.0.32apache-tomcat-6.0.33tomcat -> apache-tomcat-6.0.33
```

Ну ты понял, я типа пишу `/opt/tomcat/start.sh`  запускаю одну версию , надо другую , меняю ссылку.

Comment: Тут дело не только в том как запустить два одиниковых пакета, но разных версий - мне до этого ещё расти и расти. Вопрос - как вы устанавливаете новую версию какой-то библиотеки из исходников - но её версия выше той что в репозитории.

Comment: непонял ? Если из исходников то уже репозитории не причем. Вы в вопросе написали "скачиваю с сайта исходники и устанавливаю", если у вас вопрос как установить из исходников, то это уже другой разговор и вопрос соответственно.

Comment: Извини если не правильно изъяснялся - объясню пошагово - установил из исходников Qt 4.8.4 (как установить из исходников знаю - чай не новичок) - но появилась версия 5.2 - и тоже установка из исходников - и тут я не понимаю что делать - установить "над" существующим ? или сделать сначала "uninstall" старой версии пакета? если второе то как сделать "uninstall" пакета установленного из исходников?

Comment: к примеру появляется новая версия како-то софта который распространяется только через исходники - а в репозитории пакеты с бородой.

Comment: Слово "пакет" не применяется когда речь идет об установки из исходников, uninstall  вам не сделать тоже , вы просто можете удалить руками то что сделал make install. При установки пакета на этапе configure  вы можете указать директорию или путь к установке. Укажите отличный путь от текуще установленного. Как я писал выше у вас будет две директории qt4 и  qt5  сделаете ссылку qt  и направите ее на нужный каталог с нужной версией. Надеюсь я понятно объяснил !?

Comment: Спасибо. Кстати - каково ваше мнение насчет собирать локально пакет из исходников и потом установить его?Ибо так как я новичок - боюсь что-то удалить руками...

Comment: Это гуд! Так лучше и сделать !

Answer (score 2):

Идёте сюда - http://qt-project.org/downloads и качаете под свою архитектуру (например, под х64 качаем qt-linux-opensource-5.2.0-x86_64-offline.run), даёте права на выполнение и запускаете двумя кликами. Дальше всё понятно и в графике. Если до этого стояла 5.1 или 5.0, то да, её надо сначала снести, иначе будет две, а это уже лишнее.Если нужны компоненты, которых нет в инсталляции, то качаем исходники и компилим недостающее. Например, драйвер БД Firebird.

Удаляется Qt с помощью /home/**user**/Qt5.2.0/MaintenanceTool, где user - это Ваша учётка.

Comment: я работаю только из консоли - так что описываемый Вами вариант не сработает.